# Integration Flow Test Spring Transaction

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spock, spring-transactions, spring-test

I'm currently writing a Spock integration test for my Spring application.

I'd like to use `@Stepwise` in order to perform a test which interacts with the database and then have the next test build on top of the data left behind from the first test.

Unfortunately it seems that a new transaction is started for every test method, thus clearing the data I need to build upon. `Rollback(false)` does not prevent this behaviour, since the whole transaction is discarded AFAIK.

Here's an example, the `MyUserService` interacts with a `@Repository`-interface.

```java
@Stepwise
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
class MyServiceImplIntegrationFlowSpec extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  @Subject
  MyUserService myUserService

  @Shared
  String userId

  void "create user"() {

    when:
    userId = myUserService.createUser()

    then:
    userId
  }

  void "change user permission"() {

    when:
    myUserService.changePermission(userId, "read")

    then:
    myUserService.fetchPermission() == "read"
  }
}
```

How can I reuse the data which was created by the previous test method, as is commonly done with `@Stepwise`, in conjunction with database operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Test framework rolls back the data of each test method by default. You can change this default behaviour by adding the `@Commit` annotation to each of your test methods where you want to keep the changes in the database. If the whole test suite should commit data to the database I think you can put the `@Commit` annotation also on class level.

See the reference https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-tx

It says:

> One common issue in tests that access a real database is their effect
>   on the state of the persistence store. Even when you use a development
>   database, changes to the state may affect future tests. Also, many
>   operations — such as inserting or modifying persistent data — cannot
>   be performed (or verified) outside of a transaction.

and continues describing with

> The TestContext framework addresses this issue. **By default, the
>   framework creates and rolls back a transaction for each test**. You can
>   write code that can assume the existence of a transaction. If you call
>   transactionally proxied objects in your tests, they behave correctly,
>   according to their configured transactional semantics. In addition, if
>   a test method deletes the contents of selected tables while running
>   within the transaction managed for the test, the transaction rolls
>   back by default, and the database returns to its state prior to
>   execution of the test. Transactional support is provided to a test by
>   using a PlatformTransactionManager bean defined in the test’s
>   application context.
>
> If you want a transaction to commit (unusual, but occasionally useful
>   when you want a particular test to populate or modify the database),
>   you can tell the TestContext framework to cause the transaction to
>   commit instead of roll back by using the **@Commit** annotation.

Your test case could look like

```java
@Stepwise
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@Commit // if you want all test methods to commit to the database
class MyServiceImplIntegrationFlowSpec extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  @Subject
  MyUserService myUserService

  @Shared
  String userId

  @Commit // if a single test needs to commit to the database
  void "create user"() {

    when:
    userId = myUserService.createUser()

    then:
    userId
  }

  void "change user permission"() {

    when:
    myUserService.changePermission(userId, "read")

    then:
    myUserService.fetchPermission() == "read"
  }
}
```